# Snowflake app doesnt have access to all databases

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I created this snowflake application but I want it to have access to all my databases. Now it only has access to the database of the application and of the application package but I also have other databases with data in it and I want that my application has access to those as well. The owner of the app is `accountadmin` and I also created all the rest with the accountadmin so I dont know why it doesnt have access to all the other databases. Because when I do `SHOW DATABASES` it only lists 2 while there are more. Same for schemas in those databases when I do `SHOW SCHEMAS IN {DATABASE}` it does not list all schemas. Anyone has had experience with this before? Thanks in advance and if you need any more information reach out in the comments!

Comment: Are you talking about an application that uses the Native Apps framework? If so, are the databases in the Provider account or need to be accessible in the Consumer accounts when the app is deployed to them? If you’re not talking about a Native Apps framework then can you update your question with a description of your app’s architecture